# NSNumber to BOOL

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I am using `Parse.com` as a backend server, and am uploading data. I have a `PFObject` called person which has a column called 'Email' of `Boolean` type. I have a `Core Data` object with a BOOL property called `email`, which is set by: `[NSNumber numberWithBool:[self.email isOn]];`. When I try to set the `PFObject` as follows:

`Person[@"email"] = [person.email boolValue];`,

it gives me an error saying I am assigning a bool to id (Person is a `PFObject`). Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the type of a PFObject's email property?

The fact that you can send it a boolValue message makes me think it might be an NSNumber. (Either that or NSString)

If it's already an NSNumber, you don't have to do anything.  Simply assign the person.email directly to your destination key/value pair:

```
aPerson[@"email"] = person.email;
```

If person.email is a string, then you could use:

```
aPerson[@"email"] = @([person.email boolValue]);
```

Which would convert person.email to a bool, and then create an NSNumber using that bool.

BTW, you should not name variables, properties, or methods starting with an upper case letter. Objective-C has the strong convention that only classnames should start with an upper case letter.

I also cringe at having 2 different variables that only differ based on case ("Person" and "person"). That's a typing mistake away from a future bug.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the variable isn't actually named Person, I just typed that up as an example quickly. Thank you for your insight, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to the iOS Documentation, *boolValue* returns a primitive BOOL.  id is not primitive, and can only be assigned objects such as *NSNumber*.

When using Parse, I normally send NSNumbers up to the server, as you cannot send BOOLs.  Try writing this instead.

```
Person[@"email"] = [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.email];
```

This will send the NSNumber value up to the server, and when you need to retrieve it in BOOL form, just use NSNumber's *boolValue*